# Trying to extend ol.Tile in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers

I am upgrading my app from OpenLayers 4.6.4 to 6.4.3 and I can't access **ol.Tile** anymore.  My code is as follows which works in 4.6.4 (using ol-debug.js).  What would I do to achieve the same access to ol.Tile in OpenLayers 6 ol.js?

My index.html is:

```
<!-- OpenLayers 6.4.3 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css">
<script src="ol.js"></script>

<div tabindex="700" id="map" class="map"></div>

<script type="module">
    import MapView from './mapview.js';
    var mv = new MapView();
</script>
```

My MapView class contains the following (which works in OL4 ol-debug.js but not OL6 ol.js).  It seems that **Tile** is only available if I import ol-debug.js (which doesn't exist in OL5 and OL6).  Is there any way around this?  Or can someone help me understand how I can grab ol.Tile to extend it?  Note: my main project's codebase is a bit old and is still using RequireJS.

```
class CanvasTile extends ol.Tile {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
  }
}
```

The error I get when it tries to access Tile on ol is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Comment: Can you try this type import

<script type="text/javascript" src="path/ol-layers/ol.js"></script>

Comment: I'm already doing that as the default <script> type is javascript.  I have the ol object loaded I just don't have access to ol.Tile in the build/minified ol.js.